# Post message for direct input

Tags: vbscript, directinput

I want to simulate a mouse click in a video game that is minimized.

The video game I am doing this for allows macroing like this, so it's all good.

However, the game uses direct input so using `PostMessage` and `SendMessage` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SendInput API instead.